How do I remove a flexbox from above the header of my website?
There is simply what looks like blank space above my menu. I am trying to make a website in Wordpress and I used a theme called Kaya and am using Elementor and Mega Menu. I can't delete it in Elementor and I'm struggling to figure out how to get rid of this thing. When I scroll it shrinks until it's just my menu at the top and I have sticky menu on. I am not tech savvy so I don't know where to go to figure this out. If anyone could help I would appreciate big time!I wanted to post an image but I'm being told I need at least a 10 reputation.
I tried going into Elementor because that's all I assumed it could be in but it doesn't show up in there. The only reason I know it is a "flexbox" is because when I inspect the page I can highlight it and it tells me it is a flexbox. When I delete the line in the page code inspection menu it deletes it from the page but of course I can't save it after that and don't know if I could find somewhere to delete it from the code. I've tried looking through the mega menu too.
